# time complexity for given scenario of code

Tags: c, time, complexity-theory

what will be the time complexity for the following cases:

i)

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        printf("hello");
    }
}
```

ii)

```
for(i=0; i<n*n; i++)
{
    printf("Hello");
}
```

Comment: What have you tried on your own to solve the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i): The outer loop is running `n` times so you touch every element `n` times in the outer loop.

The inner loop is also running `n` times, so you touch every element `n*n` times so its
O(n^2)

ii) The loop is running `n*n` times so it simply is O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask yourself how much does 1 iteration costs, Lets assume x
And then ask yourself how much iteration do i have, lets assume y
So what will be the time complexity?  O(x*y)

In your both cases:
1 iteration costs O(1)
You have n*n iterations
So the time complexity O(n^2)